# Firebase cloud function invoke from your webapp only

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there is a way to invoke firebase cloud functions from your domain/webapp only not from any other services like postman or other api modules?

Comment: The typical approach is to pass along a Firebase Auth user ID token and validate it in the function.  Other than that, there is no way to fully restrict access to a particular app.